# How to match brackets [ and ] with l3regex?

Tags: l3regex

I would like to patch some commands with `\regex_replace_all:nnN`, however I was not able to match the brackets `[` and `]` as they have other meanings as regular expression.

Consider the following example, in which I wish to remove the `\begin{tabular}[t]{c}` from `\@maketitle`. (Here I use `.` to match the brackets, which is dangerous as it may hit other characters)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\meaning\@maketitle

\ExplSyntaxOn

\regex_replace_all:nnN { \c{begin}\{tabular\} .t. \{c\} } {} \@maketitle

\ExplSyntaxOff

\bigskip

\meaning\@maketitle
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\cO\[` and `\cO\]`, but it's weird that simply `\[` and `\]` don't work (unless I'm forgetting something obvious)... Hm, `\c{begin}\{tabular\} \[t\] \{c\}` seems to work...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you, it works! I thought that I had tried it, but it seems I overlooked something at the time.